# How do I calculate a logarithm in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, logarithm

I want to calculate a logarithm in iOS.  Can Objective-C do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [C functions](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/log.php) for calculating logarithms

```
#import <math.h>
double myLog = log(10);
```

You can also see here: [What kind of logarithm functions / methods are available in objective-c / cocoa-touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891963/what-kind-of-logarithm-functions-methods-are-available-in-objective-c-cocoa-t)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the same math functions which are available in C to do math operations in Objective-C.

I have used the following functions to do mathematical operations. Here the return type of these functions is double and argument should also be of double type... so

```
double number;

display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f" ,log(number)];  
display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f" ,log2(number)]; 

display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f" ,log10(number)];
display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f" ,exp(number)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Objective C is a superset of ANSI C, and iOS supports using most of the usual C libraries.

Thus, you can use the C library math.h, which include several log functions (base10, base e, float result, double result, etc.)