# solving logarithms in objective c

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, math

So I'm trying to figure out the best way to solve simple logarithms using objective c. For example ln 30 = 3.4012. I'm not too sure if there's any built in functionality in objective c to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891963/what-kind-of-logarithm-functions-methods-are-available-in-objective-c-cocoa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact it is "c" question because Objective-C is based on c, and all primitive math functions like logarithms are included in math.h
so use:

log() to find logarithms

exp() to find exponent
e.g.

```
NSLog(@"log(30.0):%f", log(30.0));
NSLog(@"exp(3.4012):%f", exp(3.4012));
```

> >

```
log(30.0):3.401197
exp(3.4012):30.000079
```

Answer (score 3):

Objective C is compatible with and includes all of standard C, so you can use the log() and exp() functions by importing math.h.